# Make postgresql timestamps unique

Tags: postgresql

I have a dataset with 6M+ rows including timestamps from about 2003 to current. In 2014 the database was migrated to postgresql and the timestamp column became unique due to the higher precision of timestamps. The original ID column was not migrated. About 300k of the timestamps are repeated at least once. I want to modify the timestamp column so that they are unique by adding precision (all non-unique timestamps only go to the second).

I have this

```
ts                    message
--------------------|---------------
2014-02-01 07:40:37 | message1
2014-02-01 07:40:37 | message2
```

I want this

```
ts                         message
-------------------------|---------------
2014-02-01 07:40:37.0000 | message1
2014-02-01 07:40:37.0001 | message2
```

Comment: The true question is, are you absolutely sure that you want to use timestamps as the keys (I'm assuming that's what you need them to be unique for)? These can be not unique for more than one reason...

Comment: Maybe make a 'select group by ts' and loop the result and perform another select and add 1 to each record?

Answer (score 0):

This should work, but it will be horribly slow I guess:

```
update the_table
  set ts = ts + '1 millisecond'::interval * x.rn
from (
   select ctid, row_number() over (order by ts) as rn
   from the_table
) x
where the_table.ctid = x.ctid;
```

The column `ctid` is an [internal unique identifier](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-system-columns.html) (actually the physical address of the row) maintained by Postgres.

You might want to add another `where` condition to pick out only those rows that need to be modified.

Comment: Am I correct that this would modify every row and just multiply it basically by its row number?

Comment: @DannyDyla: yes it would update every row, that's why I added "you might wan to add another where condition" at the end. It doesn't multiple the _value_ with the row number. The multiplication calculates the number of milliseconds for each row that are _added_ to the timestamp value (essentially first row: +1 millisecond, second row: +2 milliseconds, row #1000: +1 second and so on)

Comment: I would use `date_trunc('second', ts) = ts` as the second condition

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution is to try to add a random interval to the timestamp:

```
update t
set ts = ts + random() * interval '1000000 microsecond'
where ts = date_trunc('second', ts)
```

The chance of a collision is very low. If it occurs use [@a_horse's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34895022/131874)